# If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{T(h)}{\|h\|}=0$, then $T=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be linear such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{T(h)}{\|h\|}=0.$ Prove that $T=0.$

Attempt. I used definition of limit to zero, but i didn't get somewhere. I would like to avoid using the fact that $T(x)=Ax$ for some matrix $A.$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\ne 0$. Then $\lim_{t\to 0}\|tv\|=0$, hence 
$$\frac{Tv}{\|v\|}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{Tv}{\|v\|}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{tTv}{\|tv\|} 
=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{T(tv)}{\|tv\|}=0 $$
and so $ Tv=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ and let $w=T(v)$. Then$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{T(xv)}{\lVert xv\rVert}=0,$$and $$x>0\implies\frac{T(xv)}{\lVert xv\rVert}=\frac w{\lVert v\rVert}.$$So, $w=0$.